# Can't add Buefy of Bulma to Vuejs project

Tags: vue.js, bulma, buefy

I have a Vus.js project and I want to add the bulma framework and/or buefy.

I ran `npm install bulma` and `npm install buefy`

in main.js, I have:

```
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'

Vue.use(Buefy)
```

in App.vue, I also attempt to load bulma with:

```
<style lang="css">
@import '../node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css';
```

in assets/scss:

```
@import "~bulma";
@import "~buefy/src/scss/buefy";
```

I restarted the vue server, but bulma/buefy styling does not show.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using also Buefy on an github project: https://github.com/Bloemert/Einstein/blob/develop/src/Einstein.WebUI/ClientApp/styles/site.scss

Together with bulmaswatch: https://jenil.github.io/bulmaswatch/

Maybe the link too the github repository will help you?

I don't see what you are missing in your code. An jsfiddle example can help if you need more help.

Comment: At this point I went ahead and included it via a cdn link, but I have read that is not great for production. I don't know why it would make a difference.

Comment: Are you using webpack with a vue-loader and CSS loader?  If you don’t have errors in you’re console a missing or misconfigured loader can be a reason styling is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import on vue component only the style.scss that you defined and imported `bulma`

To avoid some problems, use `<style lang="scss" scoped>` when using buefy.

Within the file that you configured bulma, try these imports:

```
// Accessing all the bulma's core
@import '~bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass'
@import '~bulma/bulma';
```

Just a reminder, do not forgot to install this dependencies of bulma, will be needed to be fully functional

```
"nuxt-sass-resources-loader" && "node-sass": "^4.11.0"
```

Ps: For further configuration, visit the [documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/customization).